# Data-bind to variable in extender

Tags: knockout.js

Can anybody tell me how to access the `asc` variable in the below extender for a data-bind?

**HTML**

Example `css` binding:

```
<th><a href="#" data-bind="sort: { arr: myArray, prop: 'myProp' }, css: { 'up_chevron': sort.asc, 'down_chevron': !sort.asc }">Performance</a></th>
```

**Knockout**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var asc = true;
    element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    element.onclick = function () {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var prop = value.prop;
        var data = value.arr;

        asc = !asc;
        if (asc) {
            data.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] < right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
            });
        } else {
            data.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left[prop] == right[prop] ? 0 : left[prop] > right[prop] ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

};

Comment: You cant, its defined only in the scope of the init function, you need to change the code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
asc()
```

like this:

```
css: { 'up_chevron': sort.asc(), 'down_chevron': !sort.asc() }
```

Comment: That returns `ReferenceError: sort is not defined;`

Answer (score 0):

Make it a member of the handler object:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
  asc: true,
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
     var self=this;
...
        self.asc = !self.asc;
        if (self.asc) {
...
```